# python: transforming os.Path code into Pathlib code

Tags: python, pandas, pathlib, os.path

I have the following function in python to add a dict as row to a pandas DF that also takes care of creating a first empty DF if there is not yet there.
I use the library os but I would like to change to Pathlib since consulting with a Software Developer of my company I was said I should use pathlib and not os.Path for these issues. (note aside, I don't have a CS background)

```
def myfunc(dictt,filename, folder='', extension='csv'):
    if folder == '':
        folder = os.getcwd(). #---> folder = Path.cwd()
    filename = filename + '.' + 'csv'
    total_file = os.path.join(folder,filename) #<--- this is what I don't get translated
    
    # check if file exists, otherwise create it
    if not os.path.isfile(total_file):#<----- if total file is a Path object: totalfile.exists()
        df_empty = pd.DataFrame()
        if extension=='csv':
            df_empty.to_csv(total_file)
        elif extension=='pal':
            df_empty.to_pkl(total_file)
        else:
            #raise error
            pass

    
    # code to append the dict as row
    # ...
```

First I don't understand why path lib is supposed to be better, and secondly I don't understand how to translate the line above mentioned, i.e. how to really do os.path.join(folder_path, filename) with pathlib notation.

In path lib it seems to be different approaches for windows and other machines, and also I don't see an explanation as to what is a posix path (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use)).

Can anyone help me with those two lines?
Insights as to why use Pathlib instead of os.path are Welcome.
thanks

Comment: The key thing about pathlib vs os.path is that pathlib produces useful objects with properties and methods to access the relevant portions of the path rather than os.path which produces predominantly strings which need parsed using string methods (which can be clunky).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First I don't understand why path lib is supposed to be better.

`pathlib` provides an object-oriented interface to the same functionality os.path gives. There is nothing inherently wrong about using `os.path`. We (the python community) had been using `os.path` happily before pathlib came on the scene.

However, `pathlib` does make life simpler. Firstly, as mentioned in the comment by Henry Ecker, you're dealing with path objects, not strings, so you have less error checking to do after a path has been constructed, and secondly, the path objects' instance methods are right there to be used.

> Can anyone help me with those two lines?

Using your example:

```
def mypathlibfunc(dictt, filename, folder='', extension='csv'):
    if folder == '':
        folder = pl.Path.cwd()
    else:
        folder = pl.Path(folder)

    total_file = folder / f'{filename}.{extension}'
    if not total_file.exists():
       # do your thing
       df_empty = pd.DataFrame()
       if extension == 'csv':
         df_empty.to_csv(total_file)
       elif extension == 'pal':
         df_empty.to_pickle(total_file)
```

notes:

- if your function is called with `folder != ''`, then a `Path` object is being built from it, this is to ensure that `folder` has a consistent type in the rest of the function.
- child `Path` objects can be constructed using the division operator `/`, which is what I did for `total_file` & I didn't actually need to wrap `f'{filename}.{extension}'` in a `Path` object. pretty neat! [reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428/#joining)
- `pandas.DataFrame.to_[filetype]` methods all accept a `Path` object in addition to a path string, so you don't have to worry about modifying that part of your code.

> In path lib it seems to be different approaches for windows and other machines, and also I don't see an explanation as to what is a posix path

If you use the `Path` object, it will be cross-platform, and you needn't worry about windows & posix paths.